# How called view 'show' when id is in other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, relationship, rails-4-2-1

I have a link_to on **index** refinancings

```
<%= link_to "View details", refinancing_path(@refinancing) %>
```

This refinancing_path(@refinancing) is refinancings/6 for example

My route is simple:

```
resources :refinancings, except: :destroy
```

And my controller is:

```
  def show
    @refinancing = Refinancing.find(params[:id])
    # THIS GET REFINANCING THROUGH HISTORIC REFINANCING
    @hist_refin = HistoricRefinancing.consult_historic_refinancing(params[:refinancing_id])
  end
```

This is model of Historic Refinancing

```
class HistoricRefinancing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :authorization
  has_many :refinancings

  scope :consult_historic_refinancing, -> (refinancing_id) { HistoricRefinancing.where("refinancing_id = ? ", "#{refinancing_id}")  }
```

All I need is that in my view index when click on link_to show detail of refinancing for this authorization.
I receive this error on click:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"refinancings", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Sure, there isn't id, but how get this? Please, help me!

**UPDATE ######################################**

My view show is....

```
<h3>Details of refinancing</h3>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @refinancing.employee.person.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Period:</strong>
  <%= @refinancing.period.strftime("%m/%Y") %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Value</strong>
  <%= number_to_currency @refinancing.value %>
</p>
```

Just this...

Comment: Could you update with your view in detail? There is like a mistake in how you define the view!

Comment: Sounds like you could be trying to link to an unsaved object (those have nil id)

Comment: use rake routes to check route properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your comment, the logic should be:

```
<% authotization.historic_refinancing.refinancings.each do |refinancing| %>
  <%= link_to "View details", refinancing_path(refinancing) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry man, my code is in portuguese, so I translate it, and writting here I forget this... but my routes is refinancings and RefinancingsController, the error is other =(

Comment: I see, so the clue is: @refinancing may be nil . Try to check it?

Comment: Yes, is nil... but I have id

Comment: The problem is that authorization haven't refinancing_id and refinancing haven't authorization_id, but historic_refinancing have authorization_id and refinancing_id

Comment: So it becomes simple, let me update my answer and you can take a look

Comment: don't work man = ( What I do? This: <% authotization.historic_refinancing.each do |refinancing| %>
                                        <%= link_to "View details", refinancing_path(refinancing) %>
                  <% end %>  But don't work. I need do each because I need iterate in authorizations, because 1 refing can have more then one authorization

Comment: Nothing man = (
 >>>> OCIError: ORA-00904: "HISTORICS_REFINANCINGS"."AUTHORIZATION_ID": identificador inválido: SELECT  "HISTORICS_REFINANCINGSS".* FROM "HISTORICS_REFINANCINGS" WHERE "HISTORICS_REFINANCINGS"."AUTHORIZATION_ID" = :a1 AND ROWNUM <= 1